# Blog and private photo-sharing, but no user management

Tags: web-apps, photography, social-networks, sharing, blog

I'm looking for a way to share family photographs with short dairy notes with family. Kind of like Facebook but private, inaccesible to parties like Zuckerberg, Cambridge Analytica etc.

I would using an app like 23Snaps or Cluster but it is unclear to me what their business case is. Since these apps are free, i fear my family would again be 'the product' as with Facebook.
Also i would be cool if i could host my blog in the same place.

Requirements:

1. Web-application, preferably with integration for wordpress or similar
2. Authentication of users, but no user management. eg: OpenID or similar
3. Supports photo-albums and/or dairy entries
4. Bonus points for multilingual photo albums (so that i can post pictures with captions or stories in two languages, one for family one for friends)

I don't mind paying for software. I do prefer open source because it makes future migrations possible and because i have professional experience with OSS.

I don't need differential authorization, people are either in (can view pictures) or out (blog & public pics only).

EDIT: Budget < $10/month.

Comment: budget?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Pacerier, thanks, good question.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your problem? I'm sort of looking for the same thing.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke not yet, kind of stopped looking but if I get a suggestion i will look into it again :-)